# RabbitMQ fanout exchange implicit dynamic bind to all queues

Tags: rabbitmq

So, the 'amq.default' direct exchange is implicitely and dynamically bound to all queues.

I want the same thing for type=fanout

My expectation was that the pre-created exchange "amq.fanout" is exactly for that purpose, because anything else that needs bindings could/should use a custom exchange anyway.

It also seems to be impossible to bind an exchange to queues using wildcards, which would solve the problem equally sufficient.

Assume hundreds of consumers (each has its own queue) coming and going, using https://github.com/corvus-ch/rabbitmq-cli-consumer and thus not able to configure a binding itself at runtime/code, hence I need the exact same thing as "amq.default", but for fanout; preconfigured for all time, so to speak.

I read all the docs, but they concentrate too heavily on code and basically only telling the most simple explanation that fanout only sends to all queues if they are bound. Which doesn't help, because the binding part is what I can't do.

Is there any clever way to get a fanout exchange that is just always bound to all queues like the default/direct one?

I could verify the amq.fanout is basically working (the consumer receives it) by creating a bind to a queue manually.